# Appending a list to make a 4x4 matrix cipher

Tags: python

Im trying to use append so that the input from the user will give out  a 6x6 cipher text grid, now the user enters a cipher text (16 characters long) and the aim is to make it into a table e.g. DECBBEFEAACDCFEC will make a table as follows

```
  A   K   M   R
['D','B','A','C',]
['E','B','A','F',]
['C','F','C','E',]
['B','E','D','C',]
```

here is my source code trying to do this....

```
def decodecipher():
global decode
decode=input("Please enter your cipher text\n")
grid1 = []
keyword="AKMR"
for i in range(0, len(decode), 4):
    grid1.append(decode[i:i+4])
for i in range(0,4,1):
    print(grid1[i])
print("  A    K    M    R")
for i in range(0,4,1):
    grid2 = ([])
    grid2.append(grid1[i])
for i in range(len(grid2)):
    print(grid2[i])
```

so i've split it up into 4 first so it gives 4 different sets of lists, then i've tried to further split it and read them as one column each and paste it like above. But this is my output..

```
Would you like to (E)Encode , (G)Generate final cipher or (D)Decode a message?
******************************************************************************
D
Please enter your cipher text
DECBBEFEAACDCFEC

DECB
BEFE
AACD
CFEC

  A    K    M    R
CFEC
********************
***END OF PROGRAM***
********************
```

I can't understand why it only prints out the last 4 characters and does not display it as a column downwards, I can change the range so it prints out another set of 4 characters but not all of them at once and in the format I wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my personal favorite way of doing this is

```
my_input = "DECBBEFEAACDCFEC"
my_grid = zip(*[iter(my_input)]*int(len(my_input)**0.5))
```

an alternate and perhaps more readable version

```
my_grid = [my_input[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(my_input),4)]
```

if you then want to transpose the grids (turn them on their sides)

```
transposed_grid = list(zip(*my_grid))
```

as to why yours is not working each time in your for loop `range(0,4,1)` (which can be rewritten as `range(4)`) you are recreating grid2 as a new empty array and then appending that set to it ... so it only ever has one row in it ... at the end its the last row ...

Comment: sorry I'm not quite familiar with the function you have suggested

Comment: both those methods create a 2d list out of your string ... then I added some code to turn it on its side

Comment: zip is very useful function, good to inform yourself http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: this is very useful thank you, don't mean to trouble you again but the zip function isn't exactly working for me at this point, i understand the logic behind.........                                                               my_grid = [my_input[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(my_input),4)], but now i am having a problem with the zip which gives me an output of <zip object at 0x00000000030ED648> which i'm really confused about

Comment: changed it to work with python 3 in python2 zip returns a list ... in python 3 it returns a generator that you must convert to a list

Comment: @JoranBeasley thank you very much for your help, really simplified my code and helped me learn a new function in the process :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley i actually have another error sorry, it doesn't transpose the grids to give the desired format , it outputs this for some reason [('DECB',), ('BEFE',), ('AACD',), ('CFEC',)]                            i did print :      tg=list(zip(mygrid)

Comment: you need `zip(*mygrid)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley funny how one little asterix can make a difference, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I like Joran's answer, but to get the lists ordered as you specified in the question...

- First letter is Col1, Row1
- Second letter is in Col1, Row2
- Etc..

... I ended up with this:

**Code**:

```
decode="DECBBEFEAACDCFEC"
grid = []
for i in range(4):
    row = [j for j in decode[i::4]]
    grid.append(row)
```

Here, we loop through 0 to 3... Then we use a list comprehension to get every 4th character and add to a list. The list is then appended to the grid before continuing

**Output**:

```
print grid
[['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'], ['E', 'E', 'A', 'F'], ['C', 'F', 'C', 'E'], ['B', 'E', 'D', 'C']]
```

Comment: for i in range (4):
        print(grid[i])

Comment: above i used this to give the format i required, it basically loops for times adding each segment onto a new line giving the 4x4 matrix wanted, Ii don't know if that's a better way of doing it?